# ANTLR mismatched input

Tags: antlr4

I have a simple grammar like this:

```
grammar mygrammar;

the_rule : 'abc' 'xyz' ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

When I parse the text "abc xyz" with the_rule(), I get the expected string tree representation:

```
(the_rule abc xyz)
```

However, then I add the following lexer rule, which I think means "anything except for a w":

```
TEXT : ~[w]+ ;
```

Now when I parse the text "abc xyz" with the_rule(), I get an error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'abc xyz' expecting 'abc'
```

Why would the TEXT lexer rule affect this?  I think I'm misunderstanding something simple.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR lexer rules are greedy: the rule that matches the most wins. So, in your case, the entire input, `abc xyz`, is matched by `TEXT`. It doesn't matter if your parser is trying to match `abc`, the lexer operates independently from the parser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to write a preprocessor with tokens like #IFDEF / #ELSE / #ENDIF, but I cannot figure out how to distinguish between those tokens and a catchall TEXT token.  It seems ANTLR just latches onto TEXT.  I read the "Islands in the Stream" chapter in the ANTLR book, and the XML example makes sense, but it relies on TEXT not containing two specific characters:

Comment: How can I tell ANTLR to exclude my preprocessor tokens so it can distinguish those from general text?

Comment: I think you should create a new  question and explain what you're actually trying to do. You're now trying to use these small comment boxes for your actual question, which won't work. Just create a new one, and explain in detail how the "island" looks like inside the language you're parsing.