# Reading and Parsing PIPE using Antlr

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

this may be a very simple question but I am struggling heavily just matching the pipe character in my Grammar File. My grammar involves the following:

```
pipeCommand : call (PIPE call)+
            ;
```

where `call` can match any string not including '|'. I have also defined PIPE as:

```
PIPE : '|';
```

When testing my the grammar using with the input `echo | test`, I receive the error:

```
line 1:5 mismatched input '|' expecting '|'
```

I am unable to find anything so far to solve the problem. Is this a problem with lexing modes or I am completely wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a rule before your `|` rule that too matches the pipe char. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254455/antlr-mismatched-input